# Haskell map list of indices to !! operator

Tags: haskell

When checking the type of `map (!!) [1,2]` in the ghci parser I get back: `Num [a] => [Int -> a]`. This has to do with the fact that the first argument of `(!!)` should be a list. However, I want to input a list of indices into the operator to get this type `[a] -> [a]`.

**EDIT**
After the suggestion of @dfeuer to wrap it in another function I figured it would also be possible by using `flip` then. Checking the type of `(map (flip (!!)) [1,2])` give the type `[[c] -> c]` which is what I am looking for.

Comment: So you want `map (!!) [1, 2]` except the same list is passed to every element?

Comment: `[a] -> [a]` doesn't really make sense. Do you want a function that wraps a list, taking a set of indices and returning the corresponding values? `(someList !!)` would have type `Int -> a`, so `map (SomeList !!) :: [Int] -> [a]`.

Comment: Then `map (someList !!) [1,2] == [someList !! 1, someList !! 2]`.

Comment: @chepner `[a] -> [a]` makes pefect sense if the index list is fixed like it is in the original code.  For example `\x -> map (x !!) [1,2]` has that type.

Comment: Not if the input is supposed to be a list of indices, though. Though maybe `map (!! [1,2]) someList` is the desired result.

Comment: The list as provided in the example are the indices. The function that is returned should get a list and the values in that list corresponding to the indices should be returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list of indices and you want a function that selects those indices from an input list, then you want the `map` to iterate over the *indices*, not the input as you’re currently doing:

```
getIndices :: [Int] -> [a] -> [a]
getIndices indices input = map (input !!) indices
```

```
> getIndices [1, 2] "beans"
"ea"
```

If you want to write this in a more compact fashion using an inline list of indices, you can reduce away the `input` parameter like this:

```
\ input -> map (input !!) [1, 2]
\ input -> [1, 2] <&> (input !!)  -- Data.Functor.(<&>) = flip (<$>)
\ input -> [1, 2] <&> (!!) input
\ input -> (([1, 2] <&>) . (!!)) input

([1, 2] <&>) . (!!)
```

In other words, `flip map [1, 2] . (!!)`. But I think there isn’t anything to be gained from pointfree style in this case.

With a helper function (this name from `lens`):

```
flap, (??) :: Functor f => f (a -> b) -> a -> f b 
flap f x = ($ x) <$> f

(??) = flap
infixl 1 ??

index :: Int -> [c] -> c
index = flip (!!)
```

This can be written:

```
> oneTwo = flap (index <$> [1, 2])
> oneTwo "beans"
"ea"

> index <$> [1, 2] ?? "bears"
"ea"
```

Or there’s always the boring but readable option of a list comprehension or `do` notation:

```
oneTwo xs = [xs !! i | i <- [1, 2]]

oneTwo xs = do { i <- [1, 2]; pure (xs !! i) }
```

Comment: Can you check my edit. Is this indeed correct now or am I still mistaken? I am not at the level of using Data.Functor yet, so I will be coming back to this when I am.

Comment: @GertjanBrouwer: `map (flip (!!)) [1, 2]` produces a list of functions; the first function selects index 1 of its argument, the second selects index 2. You can apply all of them to the same list like `[f "beans" | f <- map (flip (!!)) [1, 2]]` or to different lists with other functions like `zip` or `<*>`; it really depends on what you want to use this for.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want

```hs
pickAndChoose :: [Int] -> [a] -> [a]
pickAndChoose indices values
  = map (values !!) indices
```

Since `!!` takes time linear in the position of the element it retrieves, this will be quite inefficient if many indices are used, especially if they are relatively large. You may wish to consider using something like `Data.Sequence` instead of lists.

Comment: So this is wrapping it another function to fix the input parameter order. Is this also possible with flip?

Comment: Well I guess that works, I checked the type of this:  `(map (flip (!!)) [1,2])` and it gives `[[c] -> c]`